# Does impeachment conviction necessarily imply removal from office?

Tags: us-constitution, president, impeachment, us-senate

The relevant bits of [Article 1 Section 3](https://www.usconstitution.net/xconst_A1Sec3.html) state that:

> Judgment in Cases of Impeachment shall not extend further than to removal from Office, and disqualification to hold and enjoy any Office of honor, Trust or Profit under the United States

This seems to imply that, if convicted, the Senate *may* then choose to remove the president, or to bar them from holding future offices.  It is not immediately clear that a conviction necessarily implies either of these punishments.

Does impeachment conviction necessarily imply removal from office?

Comment: Imply is not the best word as the "removal" is the "mandatory minimum" sentence.

Comment: @hszmv I used "imply" because I was thinking only of the text in Article I section 3.  I was overlooking Article II section 4.

Comment: I have a math/logic background.  By "x implies y" I only meant that "y follows necessarily from x".  See [definition 3 here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/imply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Article II, Section 4 of The Constitution says

> The President, Vice President and all civil Officers  of  the  United 
>   States,  **shall**  be  removed from Office on Impeachment for, and
>   Conviction of,  Treason,  Bribery,  or  other  high  Crimes  and
>   Misdemeanors.

Removal therefore follows automatically from conviction.

Comment: Isn't that restricted it to those three reasons, though? What if they're impeached for, and convicted of, something else?

Comment: Technically they cannot be impeached for anything else. However, only the House can decide what constitutes treason, bribery or other high crimes and misdemeanors, and only the Senate can decide whether they agree that the acts do constitute treason, bribery or other high crimes and misdemeanors.

Comment: Is that stated somewhere as well? (that they cannot be impeached for anything else)

Comment: If they can't be impeached for it, they can't be impeached for it. Can you refer to another section that says impeachment is possible on other grounds? @HeapOverflow

Comment: @Nij Don't know. That's pretty much my question.

Comment: So, if you haven't got reference to anything saying they can be impeached for it, why would it be expected that this can be done? @HeapOverflow

Comment: @Nij If those were all possible reasons, the quoted statement wouldn't need to list them explicitly.

Comment: Again, what makes you think that?

Comment: @Nij Logic? Common sense? Not sure why you're asking that.

Comment: I'm asking because this is a Q&A website about law, not computer science, and my common sense tells me that you specify the conditions that should trigger some kind of effect in a system.